# I want to add Telerik Grid in my Winform App but stuck on runtime exception

Tags: c#, winforms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6lcr.png)
I changed Telerik reference files but the problem not solved. please give me suggestions on how can I solve this.
how to resolved this runtime exception error!

Comment: Sounds like you may have multiple versions of Telerik installed

Comment: ok, thanks. I try to uninstall and then try to add.